# RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[60000,32,393,2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a CNN when I run it, I got this this error :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[60000,32,393,2] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 by allocator GPU_1_bfc
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d_2/Relu}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.

     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/_31]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.

  (1) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[60000,32,393,2] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 by allocator GPU_1_bfc
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d_2/Relu}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
srun: error: gpu01: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

what should be done to solve this problem ?

Comment: It's saying your graphics card is running out of memory. You can either use smaller batch sizes (assuming the entire dataset doesn't fit on the GPU) or when you make your datagen from your dataset, you can use `flow_from_directory()` if the dataset is too large to fit in memory. If you're running cross validation, you'll need to reset the graph to free GPU memory or else after each iteration, you'll reload a new subset of your dataset without clearing the previous ones.

Comment: This is too vague to be answerable, what makes you think people can give solutions with just a message saying "out of memory"?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, this shape `[60000,32,393,2]` is too big for your GPU, you need to lower this shape, by reducing the batch size or reducing the image dimensions.

This means that during the training the network needed to allocate that space for a convolution, but it went out of memory.

In alternative you need to change the structure of the CNN, by reducing the number of kernels in the layers.

Here i would try to lower the batch size of the training (`60000`).